# Table With Computed Column Derived from Last of Two Dates One or Both May be Null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to create a computed column to handle two other columns were either of them may be null?

I want to setup a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 to have a computed column based on two date columns. I have been able to create a basic computed column but am unable to have it based on two columns. The underlying date columns can be null. Note a result of null is acceptable (when both dates are null), but if one date is valid, then that date should be used to compute the days since last login.

Here is what I have so far, the computed `LastLoginCount` currently works for one date column `SHR_LastLogin` but I need it to do a "Min" of the two date columns (`SHR_LastLogin`, `AdLastLogin`) and return the latest login as a number of days.

```
CREATE TABLE [web].[UserNotifications](
    [NotificationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AdDomain] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [AdAccount] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [AdFull]  AS (([AdDomain]+'\')+[AdAccount]),
    [AdLastLogin] [date] NULL,
    [SHR_LastLogin] [date] NULL,
    [ManagerNotifiedOn] [date] NULL,
    [NotifyManager] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginCount]  AS (datediff(day,[SHR_LastLogin],getdate())),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserNotifications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NotificationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to perform an aggregate in the computed column, but you can possibly set it up using a somewhat ugly case statement ( as my first thought, there may be a more clever approach ).  See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfa01/1) for an example; it pretty much boils down to the following in the `CREATE` statement:

```
[LastLoginCount]    AS ( DATEDIFF( DAY, CASE
                        WHEN AdLastLogin > SHR_LastLogin
                          THEN AdLastLogin
                        ELSE SHR_LastLogin
                    END, GETDATE() ) ),
```

It dawns on me you're referring to the `MIN` number of days since a login; the code above has been edited to swap the LessThan operater to a GreaterThan, but the SQL Fiddle will continue to show the former.

**Edit**: Didn't initally understand / catch the `NULL` requirement, my apologies.  It just requires a little tweak in evaluation, as in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05d9d/1).

```
[LastLoginCount]    AS ( DATEDIFF( DAY, CASE
                        WHEN AdLastLogin >= ISNULL( SHR_LastLogin, AdLastLogin ) 
                          THEN AdLastLogin
                        ELSE SHR_LastLogin
                    END, GETDATE() ) ),
```

Effectively, the logic goes "If `SHR_LastLogin` is `NULL` or `AdLastLogin` is greater ( or equal ), use `AdLastLogin`; otherwise, use `SHR_LastLogin` [in the `DATEDIFF` calculation]."

Comment: I saw the < issue and swapped. Your code works if both dates are not null, but if one date is null, the result is null as well. The computed column needs to pick up on a null and return the non-null columns computed days.

Comment: I will update my post to make the null issue clearer.

Comment: @OmegaMan Sorry about that, added a tweak!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for taking the time out to clarify this with your example.